# "avrei dovuto/voluto/potuto" VS "dovevo/volevo/potevo"

Tags: verbs, conditional-mood

Mi chiedevo se qualcuno potesse darmi una spiegazione tecnica della differenza fra "avrei dovuto/voluto/potuto" e "dovevo/volevo/potevo".

Personalmente ho sempre percepito la variante con "avrei" come una frase che descrive qualcosa di meno importante rispetto alla controparte con l'imperfetto. Ad esempio "avrei dovuto chiamarlo" mi sembra abbia meno enfasi di "dovevo chiamarlo". Quindi "avrei dovuto chiamarlo" mi trasmette che sarebbe stato  meglio chiamarlo ma che non importa poi molto se non l'ho fatto (o almeno non importa come importerebbe se usassi "dovevo").

Inoltre, se presi così singolarmente e senza contesto, "avrei dovuto chiamarlo" mi fa capire chiaramente che non ho chiamato mentre "dovevo chiamarlo" potrebbe anche essere parte di "non ho potuto farne a meno, dovevo chiamarlo..." dove è quindi chiaro che invece ho chiamato.

Se torniamo per un momento alle due varianti prese singolarmente ("avrei dovuto chiamarlo" e "dovevo chiamarlo"), se supponiamo per entrambe che non abbiamo chiamato (qui manca il contesto ma facciamo questa supposizione per un momento), allora potrebbero sembrare uguali. Questo è quello che mi hanno detto due insegnanti di italiano di professione. Secondo me invece non sono uguali ma c'è una sfumatura di significato che da meno enfasi alla frase con "avrei".

Se potete fornire una spiegazione tecnica ve ne sarei grato. Se possibile includete varianti con "volevo" e "potevo" nel caso ci sia differenza.

Grazie.

Comment: Sarebbe interessante capire perché i due insegnanti siano arrivati a pensare che quelle forme possano “sembrare uguali”, visto che, come ben illustrano le risposte, sono ben distinte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La spiegazione più chiara, più semplice e allo stesso tempo più tecnica sta nell'analisi grammaticale: un *[indicativo] imperfetto* e un *condizionale passato*.

Il secondo ha solo una interpretazione di una condizione/possibilità che non è avvenuta.
Come giustamente sai e dici:

> "avrei dovuto chiamarlo" mi fa capire chiaramente che non ho chiamato

L'imperfetto ha molteplici interpretazioni che dipendono dal contesto. Senza contesto sono tutte perfettamente legittime.

"..**.dovevo chiamarlo** ...."

..., ma non avevo il coraggio

... e poi m'è uscito di mente/ e non ho trovato un telefono/ non ho fatto in tempo

...eppure non l'avevo fatto/ perché non lo facevo?**/perché non l'avevo fatto?**

...l'avrei fatto?

..., era un imperativo categorico!

...prima che fosse troppo tardi!

..., oppure no?

> Se torniamo per un momento alle due varianti prese singolarmente
>   ("avrei dovuto chiamarlo" e "dovevo chiamarlo"), se supponiamo per
>   entrambe che non abbiamo chiamato (qui **manca il contesto ma facciamo
>   questa supposizione** per un momento), allora potrebbero sembrare
>   uguali.

Senza contesto le due forme **non** possono essere considerate *equivalenti* (uguali non lo sono mai comunque). Se manca il contesto non puoi fare nessuna supposizione. Anche nella lingua parlata, in qualsiasi registro  : "...dovevo chiamarlo..." non può dare nessuna informazione

> se li consideriamo per un momento in un **contesto con parità di
>   significato** "avrei dovuto chiamarlo (ma non l'ho fatto)" e "dovevo
>   chiamarlo (ma non l'ho fatto)", pensi che la mia impressione, sul
>   fatto che "avrei dovuto chiamarlo" dia meno rilievo al mancato dovere,
>   sia corretta?

Quello che trae in inganno te e *silvia* è che quello che chiami il contesto (*con parità di significato* non ha senso), cioè l'informazione su ciò che e poi accaduto, può essere sottinteso.

Ricapitoliamo: *"avrei dovuto chiamarlo*" contiene l'informazione di per sé, è chiaro
, *"dovevo chiamarlo"* non la contiene e permette quindi tutte le varianti date sopra.

Ora vediamo cosa ti porta fuori strada:

Maria a Rosa: *"Carlo si è offeso! ..."* Questa frase è ellittica perché l'informazione (su ciò che  è accaduto) è nota ai due parlanti. (ma ancora non a te)

Rosa a Maria: *"Eh, sì...(che stupida)...dovevo chiamarlo....*". Questo caso rientra fra le varianti di cui sopra (probabilmente la seconda), la frase è incompleta perché l'informazione condivisa è ridondante (e tu a questo punto deduci che non l'ha chiamato, perché si è offeso).

Non è un registro **"parlato"**, non c'è **"enfasi"**: è una legittima scelta e, da italiano, sai bene che è dovuta alla pigrizia: si sceglie la formula più breve

Comment: tra l'altro, "dovevo chiamarlo" non implica che tu poi non l'abbia fatto, ad esempio: "dovevo chiamarlo, quindi ho preso il telefono e ho composto il numero"

Comment: grazie per la risposta. che ne pensi invece della parte sull'enfasi? se li consideriamo per un momento in un contesto con parità di significato "avrei dovuto chiamarlo (ma non l'ho fatto)" e "dovevo chiamarlo (ma non l'ho fatto)", pensi che la mia impressione, sul fatto che "avrei dovuto chiamarlo" dia meno rilievo al mancato dovere, sia corretta?

Comment: Occhio alle “è”, @bobie!

Answer (score 3):

I verbi modali all'imperfetto non ci comunicano se l'azione è avvenuta o no.

Esempio:

volevo studiare (desideravo/avevo la volontà di), dovevo uscire (avevo la necessità/l'obbligo di) > non sappiamo se poi l'azione si è verificata.

Nel caso in cui l'azione non si sia verificata il modale all'imperfetto comunica la stessa cosa del condizionale passato anche se a un registro linguistico meno controllato (lingua parlata).

Esempio:

dovevo chiamarlo/avrei dovuto chiamarlo ma non ho avuto tempo e non l'ho fatto.

Questa è la mia opinione.